# android-Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Hi i created one customised tab bar with three tabs. I loaded one tab with google link, another with the small hello world app and another with the layout which has design for different screen resolutions. When i tap on the third tab it is showing an error "Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'". But it is not showing that error when i load the third tab with small app. Why is it happening like that? Can any one help me?

Error:

```
12-08 11:50:52.004: ERROR/ACRA(1738): El Gifto fatal error : Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ibkr.elgifto/com.ibkr.elgifto.Ehome}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
12-08 11:50:52.004: ERROR/ACRA(1738): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ibkr.elgifto/com.ibkr.elgifto.Ehome}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
12-08 11:50:52.004: ERROR/ACRA(1738): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
12-08 11:50:52.004: ERROR/ACRA(1738):     at android.app.TabActivity.onContentChanged(TabActivity.java:105)
12-08 11:50:52.004: ERROR/ACRA(1738):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
12-08 11:50:52.004: ERROR/ACRA(1738):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
12-08 11:50:52.004: ERROR/ACRA(1738):     at com.ibkr.elgifto.Ehome.onCreate(Ehome.java:132)
```

thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use `TabActivity`, you need to use `@android:id/tabhost` as the `android:id` value of your `TabHost` in your xml layout file